# SSRS Report - Display Single Data Row Vertically

Tags: reporting-services

I've built a report that is being passed simple Order data on a single row.  For the "detail" fields from this row I would like to display them as follows:

```
Field1Name     Field1Value
Field2Name     Field2Value
etc...
```

For some reason, I'm having trouble getting this to work in SSRS.  Every time I add one of the fields to my Table/Matrix controls, SSRS expands the control horizontally.

How would we display data from our single row so the field names are in Column 1 and the field values are in column 2?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You cand do this if you change your query to use a PIVOT; then it will display correctly by default.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx